# How to set expiration date for audio link

Tags: audio-streaming

I wanted to upload an audio file to a website and I want to set the expiration for the file or for the link.

I don't want the users to re-play the file and I want to let them hear to the audio file only once..

Is it possible? Any kind of software or audio sharing website site does this?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an expiration on downloading the file (or streaming it directly from your server), you could simply serve the file with PHP, and throw a `403 Forbidden` or other error when the file being requested has "expired".

Note though that if anyone has downloaded the file previously, the file could still be played.  If you want to prevent this, then you need crafty usage of DRM.  I strongly suggest avoiding this route, as anyone that wants to steal your audio can easily do so, and you only inconvenience those who are legitimate users of your site.  DRM does little to deter unauthorized usage of media.